# Finding spanning spiders

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, graph-theory, graph-algorithms

Is there a polynomial-time algorithm to find—if one exists—a spanning spider
of a given graph $G$?  A spider is a tree with at most one node with degree greater than 2:

          [image]
I know that various degree conditions on $G$ (essentially, sufficiently large node degrees) guarantee the existence of a spanning spider.  But I am wondering if there is an algorithm for arbitrary $G$.  Thanks!

Comment: Googling “spanning spiders NP-complete” showed a version of [the article by Gargano, Hammar, Hell, Stacho, and Vaccaro 2004](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.disc.2004.04.005) as the first result.  Proposition 1 states that it is NP-complete.  Does this answer your question?

Comment: Seems that one can easily reduce Hamiltonian path problem to this. Given $G$, make two copies $G_1,G_2$ and for some arbitrary vertex $v \in G$ add an edge $e$ that joins the two copies of $v$. Any spanning spider in the resulting graph $H$ has to cross $e$ and be a Hamiltonian path on one of the two copies.

Comment: Thanks, Tsuyoshi & Chandra!  Yes, that answers my question.  I encountered a reference to the Gargano paper but not for NP-completeness, rather for their sufficient condition for the existence of a spanning spider.

Comment: ideally they would have posted their comments as answers :), but your solution works as well

Comment: @Suresh: In case you are not aware, I did not post it as an answer because I did not think that this question should have been asked here in the first place.

Comment: @Chandra, please convert your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question has been answered in the comments by Tsuyoshi & Chandra!  I am adding this CW answer so I can accept it to indicate the question is closed.  Thanks, everyone!

Comment: IIRC you need to wait 2 days after posting a question to accept your own answer.